# Travelling from Non-Schengen to Non-Schengen with Irish Passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, airport-transfer, connecting-flights

Just a quick question, I am travelling from Canada to Budapest on an Irish passport (all non Schengen countries) but I am connecting through Amsterdam which IS a Schengen country.  Anyone give me advice which route to take through Schipol please? Can't get an exact answer to this online. Flight connection is 2.5 hours, carry-on bags only, flying KLM on same ticket for both flights.

Comment: Budapest (Hungary) **is** in the Schengen Area.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘route’?

Comment: Amsterdam Airport (Schipol) is just one big building/terminal. All gates are connected, so when you land, check at the screen the gate of next airplane and follow the sign. You may get a long walk, but there only one "terminal" (so no need to leave building, taking buses, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

You look up the gate number for your next flight and follow the signage (which is quite good at Schiphol). Look for transfer or flight connection signs and be mindful of not following the crowds taking the stairs / escalators leading down to the exit and luggage claim area.

Since Budapest is in fact in the Schengen area, you will have to go through a passport check in Amsterdam. I would look for “EU passport” lanes or automated gates as those are usually faster but as an Irish citizen you have the right to use any lane you feel like.

Answer (score 2):

Budapest is in the Schengen area. So you will pass through passport control in Amsterdam. As you are an EU citizen, you can use automated e-Gates to enter which is usually faster than manual passport control (where an officer processes you). Then you can proceed to your gate for the Budapest flight. Amsterdam to Budapest is an intra-Schengen flight and will operate as a "domestic" flight. You will arrive in Budapest as a domestic passenger and there will be no passport control in Budapest.